# What is the use of java.lang.Class and how it relates to static method synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am reading static method synchronization in java. Where i read `static methods` get a lock on object of `java.lang.class`. I was trying to understand the concept of `java.lang.class` and its role in static method synchronization and i have these questions.

1. I was reading the blog where it says every class in Java has an instance of `java.lang.Class` and all instances of a class share this object. Instance of java.lang.Class describes type of object? What is the role of java.lang.Class here? How does it describes type of object?
2. Secondly for static method synchronization, we need to get the monitor of java.lang.Class. Why is that? Why do we need a lock on java.lang.Class monitor? Why not on the instance of our own class for example Test(my own custom class)?

Can someone elaborate on it. I am really sorry because it sounds a pretty basic question but i am pretty new to this concept.

Comment: can you please re-frame the last part of your second question. I have difficulty in understanding it.

Comment: hi @Ankur, i have re-edited the second point. Please let me know if its clear this time.

Comment: Every `Object` has a `Class` which is an `Object` itself that has a `Class` which which would be `Class<Class>`. Confusing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tentative explanation, although admittedly it is not fully correct. For whatever class `C`, when you do:

```
final C c = new C();
```

two `Object`s are involved here: the `Class<C>` object (which is provided via the context classloader) and the `c` instance. `c` will know which class it is via its `.getClass()` method (defined in `Object`).

The fact that the `new` keyword is able to establish a "backlink" to the correct `Class` is the responsibility of the JVM implementation. While this is certainly mentioned in the JLS, I cannot tell where...

Now, more to the point.

If you have a method declared as:

```
synchronized void whatever() { someCode(); }
```

then it is roughly equivalent to (why roughly: see below):

```
void whatever()
{
    synchronized(this) {
        someCode();
    }
}
```

That is, this code is synchronized at the instance level.

If the method is static however, this:

```
public static synchronized void meh() { someOtherCode(); }
```

is roughly equivalent to (why roughly: see below):

```
public static void meh()
{
    synchronized(getClass()) {
        someOtherCode();
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that all `Class` objects are singletons; no matter how many instances of class `C` you create, `.getClass()` will always return the same `Class` object. Try this:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    final String s1 = "foo";
    final String s2 = "bar";
    System.out.println(s1.getClass() == s2.getClass()); // true
}
```

Add the fact that `getClass()` is equivalent to `this.getClass()` and you get the picture. `Class` itself being an `Object`, it obeys the monitor rules of any `Object`.

And since here we always refer to the exact same object, monitor rules apply ;)

Now, "roughly": in the code written above, the logic is the same; however, depending on how you write that code, the bytecode may differ; but the JIT will have its say in it and will eventually optimize code paths.

Comment: in your first line you mean, every class in java is created by java.lang.Class?

Comment: No, I don't really mean "created". It is the JVM which will allocate the necessary space for creating the new instance, and it will also be responsible for the "backlink" to the creating class. This also explains why you can invoke static methods from a class instance, even if said instance is `null`: you do not need the instance reference, only the class reference. Not sure I explain myself clearly, this topic is ultimately simple but the basics are hard to explain...

Comment: can you explain first two lines of your answer. I am a little confused at them. Yes precisely, basics are hard to understand.

Comment: I'll try my best, but give me a couple of minutes ;) I need to ponder a coherent answer

Comment: :) by all means. Other ways i am immensly thankful how you have explained it.

Comment: OK, I have added some more information, but... Well, I am personally not satisfied. There is, of course, a chicken-and-egg problem. Which would require delving into the depths of classloaders, etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Every *object* in java is an *instance* of some *class*. In addition to that every *class* is an *object* too, so it is an *instance* of some *class* too.

> Instance of java.lang.Class describes type of object?

Not exactly. `java.lang.Class` is a *class* of *class instance*.

> What is the role of java.lang.Class here? How does it describes type of object?

It describes type of all types.

> Secondly for static method synchronization, we need to get the monitor of java.lang.Class. Why is that? Why do we need its instances lock not our class lock?

You need to synchronize on some object. Static methods have no access to `this`, by definition, so the only shared thing that is left is a **class where they are defined**.

Answer (score 1):

> Secondly for static method synchronization, we need to get the monitor
>   of java.lang.Class. Why is that? Why do we need a lock on
>   java.lang.Class monitor? Why not on the instance of our own class for
>   example Test(my own custom class)?

There are two ways to synchronize static methods. One is this :

```
static synchronized void methodName(){}
```

In this case, user need not care about acquiring the lock externally. Internally all the static methods of this class which are marked as **synchronized** will need to acquire the lock to its java.lang.class instance. It is very obvious in this case that, instance(new Class()) locks cannot be acquired over here as the method is static, and static methods can exist without instances of the class. Also static methods are shared by all the objects of that class. So instances of this class is out of question.

Other way is to use synchronized block inside static method :

```
    static void methodName() {

         synchronized(ClassName.class){ // same as above approach
         // method defination
         }

   synchronized(this){ } // not allowed. compile time error


   // to get lock of instance of this class you do as shown below. But it is not useful at all.  Because every time u acquire different instance. So synchronization is not achieved. 
synchronized(new Class()){ } 
       }
```

OR

```
static OtherClass lock = new OtherClass();
       static void methodName() {

             synchronized(lock){ // instance of other class can be used a well
             // method defination
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `java.lang.Class` is a representation of your class. The primary use of the class `Class` is to use reflection (gettings constructors and methods for example).

For this think of it as a meta object... all instances of one class share this meta object.

The designers of java have chosen that monitors have to work on objects. To have a monitor on a static method you have to use the afore mentioned meta object (or class).

I think that this made the design and implementation of the monitor for synchronized blocks easier. Also, as mentioned, the class `java.lang.Class` is used for reflection and therefore is there already.